Cannot find table row tags when scraping page
I am scraping the first few pages of a site. This has recently stopped working after the 10th page:
        page += 1
        rankings_url = f'{URL_RANKINGS}{page}'
        res = get(rankings_url)
        html = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
        rows = html.find_all('tr', id='row_')
        logger.info(f'Found {len(rows)} rows for page {page}...')

This works for the first 10 pages. However, from page 11 and onward, there are no rows. When I look in the inspector for the request the rows are in the response, as well as when I look at the source.
I cannot figure out what the problem could be - it used to work. I'm just fetching it with requests:
        res = requests.get(
            url, params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30, allow_redirects=redirect
        )

The headers and params would be empty, or None and redirect is True.
Page in question: https://boardgamegeek.com/browse/boardgame/page/11

Could you briefly clarify whether you are logged in or not - in case of doubt, you will run into the paywall / login, as you will be automatically redirected to this after the 10th page.

@HedgeHog thanks, that seems to be the issue. I'm now trying to log in, and want to check my status by going to https://boardgamegeek.com/api/accounts/current but now I get a 404 using requests. Any idea what that could be?

the username bggusername and SessionID cookies are required, you can solve this by creating a session (requests.session) and logging in using said session.

Are you maintaining the session across requests after logging in? Sometimes it expires after a certain number of requests. Ensure that you are using a requests.Session() to persist the login session.
You can try accessing other API endpoints or pages that require authentication to see if your session persisted.
